# Creating a Generic<T> type instance with a variable containing the Type

Tags: c#, generics, types, instance

Is it possible to achieve the following code?  I know it doesn't work, but I'm wondering if there is a workaround?

```
Type k = typeof(double);
List<k> lst = new List<k>();
```

Comment: Bit confused by your comment "this can be accomplished in C# 4.0."  It can't, at least not in the way you show it.  C# 4 still requires generic type parameters to be specified at compile time; you still can't pass a Type variable as a generic type parameter.

Comment: Please phrase things as a question when it is a question. The code as specified can not be accomplished with C# 4.0.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687363/how-do-i-create-a-generic-class-from-a-string-in-c

Comment: Sorry about the C# 4.0 thing.  I meant that the answer could use concepts in C# 4.0, not necessarily that the code would work in C# 4.0.  Thanks for the edit DrJokepu.

Comment: Doesn't generics already do this!?!?

Comment: I think this question is stated perfectly -- just the right amount of detail!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically Create a generic type for template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67370/dynamically-create-a-generic-type-for-template)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
var genericListType = typeof(List<>);
var specificListType = genericListType.MakeGenericType(typeof(double));
var list = Activator.CreateInstance(specificListType);
```

Comment: I think this is what I want.  Let me double check and I'll mark yours as the answer momentarily.

Comment: I think the main problem here is that you don't describe what you want to *us*. You show us a failed attempt at *something* and then asks how to accomplish what *you want*. If you want answers, and not guesses, you should describe what you need to do, instead of how you attempted to do it.

Comment: I basically want to create a List<> where the type is specified as a Type variable.

Comment: Thanks David M, your code does exactly what I needed.  Sorry to those who were unable to answer because I didn't provide an adequate question.

Answer (score 3):

A cleaner way might be to use a generic method.  Do something like this:

```
static void AddType<T>()
    where T : DataObject
{
    Indexes.Add(typeof(T), new Dictionary<int, T>());
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Indexes", is that a variable declared elsewhere?