# use Type.GetType(string) in C# 2.0 .net but type or namespace name 't' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, c#-2.0, castle

I'm not sure how to correct this.  I have

```
public void get_json(String TYPE)
{
    Type t = Type.GetType("campusMap." + TYPE); 
    t[] all_tag = ActiveRecordBase<t>.FindAll();
}
```

But I always just get

> Error 9   The type or namespace name 't' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:_SVN_\campusMap\campusMap\Controllers\publicController.cs    109 17  campusMap

any ideas on why if I'm defining the type I am wishing to gain access to is saying it's not working?  I have tried using reflection to do this with no luck.  Anyone able to provide a solution example?

**[EDIT] possible solution**

This is trying to use the reflection and so I'd pass the string and invoke the mothod with the generic.

```
        public void get_json(String TYPE)
        {
            CancelView();
            CancelLayout();
            Type t = Type.GetType(TYPE);
            MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("get_json_data");
            MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(t);
            generic.Invoke(this, null);
        }
        public void get_json_data<t>()
        {
            t[] all_tag = ActiveRecordBase<t>.FindAll();
            List<JsonAutoComplete> tag_list = new List<JsonAutoComplete>();
            foreach (t tag in all_tag)
            {
                JsonAutoComplete obj = new JsonAutoComplete();
                obj.id = tag.id;
                obj.label = tag.name;
                obj.value = tag.name;
                tag_list.Add(obj);
            }
            RenderText(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tag_list)); 
        }
```

and the error I get is in..

```
        obj.id = tag.id;
```

of 
            't' does not contain a definition for 'id'

and same for the two name ones.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting generic type at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604743/setting-generic-type-at-runtime)

Comment: I don't see it as beuing the same.. but I could be wrong.

Comment: The problem is the same - trying to use a `Type` variable as a generic type argument, and your problem would be fixed by the solutions in the answers; specifically, http://stackoverflow.com/a/2604844/79439

Comment: I don't know.. That answer may be clear to you but Digitlworld's seems more clear to me here .. :/ why I'm working this out, just not sure how to use that one you pointed out.

Comment: The additional problem here is you're using a generic type in a way that the compiler would have to know ahead of time the members it contains. It can't find `tag.id`, because it doesn't know, not really, what the type of `tag` is.

The other pitfall is that the `t` in `MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("get_json_data");` needs to be whatever type that `get_json_data<t>` is declared in. You should probably read up on both reflection and generics. It's a very broad topic, but for what you're trying to do, a clear understanding of both topics is paramount.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Dynamic Generic Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078914/c-sharp-dynamic-generic-type)

Comment: Ok.. there is no way that it can be both a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/2604743/746758 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2078914/746758 as they are not duplicates of each other.. just saying, all 3 have different resolutions to the nuanced of an issue that has many facets during implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass a variable in as a generic parameter:

```
t[] all_tag = ActiveRecordBase<t>.FindAll();
```

It's complaining about the `<t>` part. You can't do that.

I suggest you check this out: [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Outside of that, I'd probably do everything you want to do with the generic type in a generic method, and then use reflection to call *that* generic function with the runtime type variable.

```
public void get_json<t>()
{
    t[] all_tag = ActiveRecordBase<t>.FindAll();
    //Other stuff that needs to use the t type.
}
```

And then use the reflection tricks in the linked SO answer to call the `get_json` function with the generic parameter.

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(Sample).GetMethod("get_json");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeVariable);
generic.Invoke(this, null);
```

Comment: I edited the question to reflect the possible suggestiong here. tk

Comment: "You can't pass a variable in as a generic parameter" Is fully right... and What I ended up doing was setting up an interface and then made the the class types I needed to call from the parameter the  and they inherite from that.

Answer (score 4):

Your program indicates a fundamental misunderstanding about how C# works. The type of all_tag and the type value of the type argument must both be known to the compiler *before* the program is compiled; you do not determine that type until the program is already running, which clearly is *after* it is compiled.

You can't mix static compile-time typing with dynamic runtime typing like this.  Once you are doing something with Reflection, the *whole thing* has to use Reflection.

Comment: No I get that it is supost to be "knowen" .. but that is not what the need is.  the point is that I have to have a dynamic part here, or face 35+ copy pasting of the same 6 line method where I only change <t> ... and that seems like C# has to have a solution too that is clean and clear.  I know moving to 3.5 would give dynamic types but we can't do that.  Open to ideas :D

Answer (score 0):

Can you delegate the choice of type to the calling code?  You can't specify a runtime type as a generic, compile-time type, but if you could delegate the choice of type to the caller, you might be able to accomplish what you want.

```
public ??? get_json<T>() // seems like this should return something, not void
{
     var collection = ActiveRecord<T>.FindAll();
     // do something with the collection
}
```

Called as

```
get_json<CampusMap.Foo>();
```

Even if you didn't know the type at compile time, it <strike>might</strike> would be easier to call this way via reflection, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/232621.