# Reflection: Calling Method with generic list as a result

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have the following example-class:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public IList<T> GetAll()
    {
        return null; // of course, something more meaningfull happens here...
    }
}
```

And I would like to invoke `GetAll` with reflection:

```
Type myClassType = typeof(MyClass<>);
Type[] typeArgs = { typeof(object) };
Type constructed = myClassType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
var myClassInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed);

MethodInfo getAllMethod = myClassType.GetMethod("GetAll", new Type[] {});
object magicValue = getAllMethod.Invoke(myClassInstance, null);
```

This results in (on last line of above code):

> Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.

Okay, second try:

```
MethodInfo getAllMethod = myClassType.GetMethod("GetAll", new Type[] {});
getAllMethod = getAllMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(object));
object magicValue = getAllMethod.Invoke(myClassInstance, null);
```

This results in (on second last line of above code):

> System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] GetAll() is not a GenericMethodDefinition. MakeGenericMethod may only be called on a method for which MethodBase.IsGenericMethodDefinition is true.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where did `baseRepo` come from in the last line? Shouldn't it be `myClassInstance`?

Comment: Your sample code must have a bug in this line: MethodInfo getAllMethod = myClassInstance.GetMethod("GetAll", new Type[] {});

Comment: Yes, OP probably used ``myClassType`` there instead of ``constructed``. After I corrected that, it worked for me.

Comment: Example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method

Comment: Sorry for the code-errors, happend from simplifying it... fixed that.

Comment: Hopefully it's a lesson for the future - if you're going to simplify the example, make sure it compiles and gives the same problem - if it does, great. If it *doesn't*, greater still - you're isolating the difference between your example and your real code, and may be able to solve the problem entirely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting generic type at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604743/setting-generic-type-at-runtime)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've tried this and it works:

```
// Create generic type
Type myClassType = typeof(MyClass<>);
Type[] typeArgs = { typeof(object) };   
Type constructed = myClassType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

// Create instance of generic type
var myClassInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed);    

// Find GetAll() method and invoke
MethodInfo getAllMethod = constructed.GetMethod("GetAll");
object result = getAllMethod.Invoke(myClassInstance, null);
```

Comment: Thx - it was a silly mistake... `constructed.GetMethod("GetAll");` is correct of course, or in my case `myClassInstance.GetMethod("GetAll", new Type[] {});`

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed (not sure if it's just an error in your sample) that there is a problem with your code. `myClassInstance` will be of type `object` and so you cannot call `GetMethod(...)` on it. I think you may mean to call that on the type instead. Secondly, you are passing `baseRepo` as the object to invoke the method on - surely you want to invoke the method on the instantiation of the type - in this case, the variable `myClassInstance`?

If you modify your code this way, you should have something like the below code (which, when testing, works):

```
Type classType = typeof(MyClass<>);
Type[] typeArgs = { typeof(object) };
Type fullClassType = classType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

var classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(fullClassType);

MethodInfo method = fullClassType.GetMethod("GetAll", new Type[0]);
object result = method.Invoke(classInstance, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
 public static void TestMethod()
 {
     Type myClassType = typeof(MyClass<>);
     Type[] typeArgs = { typeof(object) };
     Type constructed = myClassType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
     var myClassInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed);

     MethodInfo getAllMethod = constructed.GetMethod("GetAll", new Type[] { });
     object magicValue = getAllMethod.Invoke(myClassInstance, null);
 }
```

There are some errors in your code, as following:

- You need to call `GetMethod(...)` on the type object of your generic class (not on instance).
- `getAllMethod.Invoke(...)` requires the instance of the generic class you have created using `Activator`.

Answer (score 0):

If this is how you are using it, why are you bothering to make MyClass generic?  This would be significantly faster:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public IList GetAll()
    {
        return null; // of course, something more meaningfull happens here...
    }
}
```

and then just call

```
var myObject = new MyClass();
var myList = myObject.GetAll();
```

Comment: My guess would be that making it of Type object was just for the example, to make it as easy to understand as possible

Comment: Exactly: It is a simplified example. There is good reason why it is like that and why I have to use reflection on an other place.