# Passing variable type to generic method

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a generic method :

```
public static T GetSetting<T>(string Key){
   ....
}
```

Which returns a setting value from database.
Now I'm trying to make it fill the class automatically with Settings:

```
    public static T GetAllSettings<T>(this T m)
            {
                FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public);
                foreach(FieldInfo f in fields)
                   f.SetValue(m, User.GetSetting<f.FieldType>(f.Name), null);
//                                               ~ <=Error in here      
            }
```

But I'm getting the error:

> 'f' is a variable but is used like a type

Well I'm actually getting the `f` FieldType and not the `f` itself

Comment: The type needs to be known at compile time, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604743/setting-generic-type-at-runtime

Comment: Pass `object` as the generic parameter, as `SetValue` already expects an `Object`

Comment: Your options are either do as haim770 suggests or use reflection to call `GetSetting<T>`. However, if you're doing this a lot, you may be better of just serialising your settings class to JSON/XML/binary and deserialising it back later.

Comment: @haim770 Thanks a lot problem solved. no errors. Let me finish the method to see the result in action ;). I think you should add it as answer.

Comment: What does `User.GetSetting<T>` do? It looks like you should create non-generic overloads which take a `Type` parameter and have the generic versions call those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `SetValue()` already expects an `Object` as the parameter, you could simply pass `object` as the generic parameter of `SetMethod()`:

```
f.SetValue(m, User.GetSetting<object>(f.Name), null);
```