# Is there a way to set a generic type to a Blazor component at runtime?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, blazor

`<GenericInputFor>` provides markup based on the argument it receives and its type, it behaves fine with compile time types, but when I try to iterate through some class properties with reflection it says that *the type cannot be inferred* :

```
 @foreach (var property in typeof(SomeClass).GetProperties())
        {
           <GenericInputFor Model="property.GetValue(in2,null)" ModelChanged="@((ChangeEventArgs __e) => property.SetValue(in2, __e.Value))"></GenericInputFor>
        }

@code {
    public SomeClass in2 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        in2 = new SomeClass();
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
}
```

I have seen multiple awesome solutions like [Setting generic type at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604743/setting-generic-type-at-runtime) and [Creating a Generic type instance with a variable containing the Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078914/creating-a-generict-type-instance-with-a-variable-containing-the-type) but I couldn't apply it to blazor components.

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting the `TItem` attribute on the element:

```html
@foreach (var property in typeof(SomeClass).GetProperties())
{
    <GenericInputFor TItem="typeof(SomeClass)" Model="property.GetValue(in2,null)" ModelChanged="@((ChangeEventArgs __e) => property.SetValue(in2, __e.Value))"></GenericInputFor>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but if you follow closely, the argument type is not ```SomeClass``` it is a type of a property belonging to ```SomeClass``` that is determined at runtime via reflection

Comment: Right...you can do an `@typeparam TItem` then use that reference instead of `SomeClass`