# Find out if class implements an interface thru reflection

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following class in c#:

```
public class WorkOrderStatus : ICustomEnum<WorkOrderStatus>
{
}
```

during runtime I need to figure out if a property of the following class implements the custom interface.

```
public class WorkOrder{
    public WorkOrderStatus Status {get;set;}
}
```

So I tried to do the following(using reflection to figure it out):

```
prop.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICustomEnum));
```

But this says that ICustomEnum requires a generic type. So i Tried to do the following, but it doesnt work:

```
var type = prop.GetType(); 
prop.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICustomEnum<typeof(type)>));
```

saying type is a variable but used like a type

[Edit 1]

I later need to be able to create an instance of `WorkOrderStatus` or any other class that implements this interface thru reflection like this:

```
var instance = (ICustomEnum<WorkOrderStatus|SomeOtherStatus...>)Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting generic type at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604743/setting-generic-type-at-runtime) `MakeGenericType` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple to do with `IsAssignableTo`:

```
Type propertyType = typeof(WorkOrder).GetProperty("Status").PropertyType;
Type interfaceType = typeof(ICustomEnum<>).MakeGenericType(propertyType);
bool implements = propertyType.IsAssignableTo(interfaceType);
```

---

And, you might find that `typeof(ICustomEnum<>).MakeGenericType(propertyType);` solves your problem in your code directly.

So instead of `typeof(ICustomEnum<typeof(type)>)` you write `typeof(ICustomEnum<>).MakeGenericType(type)`.

---

Here's how you would use reflection to call a method so that you can move from run-time types back to compile-time types.

```
void Main()
{
    Type propertyType = typeof(WorkOrder).GetProperty("Status").PropertyType;
    Type interfaceType = typeof(ICustomEnum<>).MakeGenericType(propertyType);
    bool implements = propertyType.IsAssignableTo(interfaceType);
    if (implements)
    {
        object propertyInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(propertyType);
        var method =
            this
                .GetType()
                .GetMethod("SomeMethod", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
                .MakeGenericMethod(propertyType);
        method.Invoke(this, new[] { propertyInstance });
    }
}

private void SomeMethod<T>(ICustomEnum<T> customEnum)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Success with {typeof(T)}");
}
```

That outputs the following:

```
Success with WorkOrderStatus
```

Here's the sundry code you need to run the above:

```
public class WorkOrderStatus : ICustomEnum<WorkOrderStatus> { }
public interface ICustomEnum<T> { }
public class WorkOrder
{
    public WorkOrderStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you give an example of how i can use the new type to cast an instance to it? (I edited the question to give a sample of what i need)

Comment: @AnKing - You can't cast it as you're dealing with types at run-time and casting only works when you know the types at compile-time. The only thing you can do is call a method using reflection that then brings the code back to being compile-time safe.

Comment: can you elaborate on "call a method using reflection that then brings the code back to being compile-time safe"? How can i do so? when i create an instance using `Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType)` it just returns me an `object`

Comment: @AnKing - There you go.

Comment: Awesome! I must be really slow but I cannot figure out what `this` refers to in the latest update

Comment: @AnKing - Sorry, `this` class that contains `SomeMethod`. You can replace it with an instance of a class that contains the method.

Comment: For some reason when i create a `WorkOrderStatus` using Activator it comes back with instance that doesnt implement `SomeMethod` so that `instance.GetType().GetMethod("SomeMethod"....` returns null

Comment: @AnKing - I didn't expect `WorkOrderStatus` to contain the method. How have you got it defined?

Comment: @AnKing - Did you run my code without any changes and see it work?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`GetGenericTypeDefinition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition?view=net-6.0) for this purpose. For example,

```
propertyInfo.PropertyType
           .GetInterfaces()
           .Where(x => x.IsGenericType)
           .Any(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICustomEnum<>));
```

To retrieve all properties of the Type which implements the particular generic interface, you could

```
var properties = typeof(WorkOrder).GetProperties();
var result = properties.Where(property=>property.PropertyType
                                               .GetInterfaces()
                                               .Where(x => x.IsGenericType)
                                               .Any(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICustomEnum<>)));
```

Comment: what if it implements ICustomEnum<UnknownType> and not the "WorkOrderStatus"? the type "WorkOrder" is not known at runtime and also derived thru reflection. Also this doesnt help me to create an instance of this class thru Activator and cast it to the proper interface

Comment: Do you need property which implements the generic interface `ICustomEnum<>` or a specific version of it ?

Comment: I edited the question to give more context