# Call extension method for type from instance extension

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I've extended the Enum type as such:

```
public class Enum<TEnum> where TEnum : notnull, Enum, IConvertible {
    public static int Length => Enum.GetNames(typeof(TEnum)).Length;
}
```

I've also extended Enums as follows:

```
public static class EnumExt {
    public static int EnumCount<TEnum>(this TEnum val) where TEnum : notnull, Enum {
        // return Enum.GetNames(val.GetType()).Length;
        return Enum<TEnum>.Length;
    }
}
```

My main window looks something like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    private void PerformTest(Enum? ptr) {
        if(ptr is null) {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: There is no value selected.");
        } else {
            Debug.WriteLine("Count: {0}", ptr.EnumCount());
        }
    }
}
```

I need to be able to access the static methods in the class Enum<TEnum> from methods in EnumExt. If I uncomment the commented line in EnumExt, it works fine. The problem is that this line is only representative of many lines in many methods and I don't want to rewrite them all for both classes or write a big select in PerformTest() to cover every possible Enum type. Speed or memory isn't really much of a concern but I need this to work without knowing the specific Enums being used beforehand (they will be known at compile time though, IDK if that needs to be said) which is why I'm using the Enum? in PerformTest(). I've spent WAY too long trying to figure this out. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `PerformTest` method a generic one too:

```
void PerformTest<TEnum>(TEnum? ptr) where TEnum : struct, Enum, IConvertible{
    if(ptr is null) {
        Debug.WriteLine("Error: There is no value selected.");
    } else {
        Debug.WriteLine("Count: {0}", ptr.Value.EnumCount());
    }
}
```

Otherwise the generic type passed to `EnumExt.EnumCount<T>` will be determined as `System.Enum` (generics are compile time construct and generic parameters are determined during compilation, alternative - using reflection to [call generic type with "runtime" type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2604844/2501279)).

P.S.

1. I highly recommend to add `struct` constraint (as I do with my take on `PerformTest`) when working with generic enum parameters.
2. `Enum.GetValues` has [a generic overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-7.0#system-enum-getvalues-1) since .NET 5 which should be more performant than non-generic one.
3. Either way - switch to auto-property (otherwise the `Enum.GetNames(typeof(TEnum)).Length` will be invoked every time):

```
public class Enum<TEnum> where TEnum : notnull, Enum, IConvertible
{
    public static int Length { get; } = Enum.GetNames(typeof(TEnum)).Length;
}
```

Comment: Awesome help. I'd hoped to get an answer that would've completely gotten rid of the select but this gets it down to just one at the start.