# Get Type T from String

Tags: c#, generics, types, casting

I got method:

```
void EmberIU<T>() where T : Form
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ins.Length; i++)
        ins[i].Click += delegate { ShowForm<T>("arg")); };
}
```

Can I use that Method like:

```
var thing = Type.GetType("namespace.class");

EmberIU<thing>()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/2078914/395718

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `Type.MakeGenericType(params Type[])` method (see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For example:

```
Type yourType = Type.GetType("namespace.class");
Type emberType = typeof(EmberIU<>).MakeGenericType(yourType);
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. The type parameter must be defined at compile time.

When you want to implement this you have to use Reflection. Take a look at [Jon Skeets answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2107864/993547).

Comment: Wrong, you can most definitely call a method with a dynamic type at runtime. It's just not as simple as the OP thinks.

Comment: @James: Can you pass a variable at type parameter?

Comment: Not like the OP is suggesting, however, via Reflection you can *invoke* a generic method.

Comment: @James: Then we agree on that. Already updated my answer.