# c# Create generic list dynamically at runtime

Tags: c#, list, generic-list

Following the example on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078914/creating-a-generict-type-instance-with-a-variable-containing-the-type), I found out how to create a list of generic types dynamically.
Now, my issue is that I want to **ADD** items to the created list from an unknown source list - is there some way to achieve this?

**EDIT**
I start with a source list containing business objects, but I absolutely need the right type of my output list, because of downstream bindings that require it.

My non-compiling code is as follows:

```
IList<object> sourceList; // some list containing custom objects
Type t = typeof(IList).MakeGenericType(sourceList[0].GetType());
IList res = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
foreach (var item in sourceList) {
    reportDS.Add(item); // obviously does not compile
}
```

Comment: what happens if you cast item to the type of the list

Comment: What are `sourceList` and `reportDS`?  Do you know what type _it_ is at compile time?  If not why don't you just use a `List<object>`?

Comment: You're using `typeof(IList)` when you actually need to say `typeof(List<>)`

Comment: `sourceList` is `IList<object>`, but I need to cast to the correct type `typeof(sourceList[0])` because of downstream bindings on that list which require the list to have the correct type... I amen the post to avoid this obvious answer!

Comment: `IList` won't work like @Sean pointed out... even the example you reference shows that they are using `List`

Comment: `AddItem` isn't a method on `IList`. Did you mean `Add` ?

Comment: Do the bindings require that the _list_ have a specific type or that the _objects_ within it be a specific type?  You could call `Cast` or `OfType` downstream if you know the type _there_.  Mixing reflection and generics is, as you can see, messy.

Comment: So why not just do `reportDS = sourceList.Cast<Newtype>()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend moving your code into a generic class or function, moving the reflection to a higher level:

```
private static List<T> CloneListAs<T>(IList<object> source)
{
    // Here we can do anything we want with T
    // T == source[0].GetType()
    return source.Cast<T>().ToList();
}
```

To call it:

```
IList<object> sourceList; // some list containing custom objects
// sourceList = ...

MethodInfo method = typeof(this).GetMethod("CloneListAs");
MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(sourceList[0].GetType());

var reportDS = genericMethod.Invoke(null, new[] {sourceList});
```

Answer (score 14):

There's a few reasons this code doesn't work.

Firstly, you need to create an instance of a concrete type. You're taking a non-generic interface (`IList`) and trying to create a generic type from it. You need `typeof(List<>)`.

Secondly, you're calling `AddItem` which isn't a method on `IList`. You need to call `Add`, which is why the code doesn't compile.

This code will do what you want:

```
IList<object> sourceList; // some list containing custom objects
Type t = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(sourceList[0].GetType());
IList res = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(t);

foreach(var item in sourceList)
{
    res.Add(item);
}
```

However, the assumption that `sourceList[0]` holds the correct type may come to bite you. If that list contains a sequence of objects that are not type compatible with the first item in the list then any attempt to add to `res` will fail. As was mentioned in the comment, you'd be better off creating a `List<object>` to hold the items.