# Instantiate all class objects serialized from xml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have deserialized a XML file into a class that make my soap request object.
When I'm serializing C# class most of classes object not fill the output xml file.

Example

```
GetUserReq.Envelope getUser = new GetUserReq.Envelope();
getUserResponse = new GetUserRes.Envelope();
getUser.Body = new GetUserReq.Body();
getUser.Body.GetUser = new GetUserReq.GetUser();
getUser.Body.GetUser.ReturnedTags = new GetUserReq.ReturnedTags();

if (allReturnTags)
{
    getUser.Body.GetUser.ReturnedTags.AssociatedGroups = new GetUserReq.AssociatedGroups();
    getUser.Body.GetUser.ReturnedTags.AssociatedDevices = new GetUserReq.AssociatedDevices();
    getUser.Body.GetUser.ReturnedTags.AssociatedGroups.UserGroup = new GetUserReq.UserGroup() { Name = "", UserRoles = new GetUserReq.UserRoles() };
    getUser.Body.GetUser.ReturnedTags.AssociatedGroups.UserGroup.UserRoles = new GetUserReq.UserRoles() { UserRole = "" };
}
```

For each item nested in the "envelope", I need to create new object otherwise the output xml file will be empty by that tag.

There are any method could do a iteration and made what I need?

These is  a snippet code where start Envelope

```
public class GetUserReq {
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public class Envelope
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Header", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
            public string Header { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
            public Body Body { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "soapenv", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
            public string Soapenv { get; set; }
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ns", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
            public string Ns { get; set; }
        }
```

and go on with body that contains other classes

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "getUser", Namespace = "http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/9.1")]
        public GetUser GetUser { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: is `Envelope` a custom class? or it's coming from some third-party library? if these classes are custom, you should add them to your question

Comment: No envelope is the root element of my xml that contains the other..

Comment: did you try to initialize these sub classes on the constructor?

Comment: Yes i can, but i'm looking for a solution because i have a lot of file and a lot of classes with properties nested inside like list or other type of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection.

```cs
public object CascadeInitializer(Type type)     
{
    var newObj = Activator.CreateInstance(type); // create new instance of your target class
    Func<PropertyInfo,bool> query = q
        => q.PropertyType.IsClass &&            // Check if property is a class
           q.CanWrite &&                        // Check if property is not readOnly
           q.PropertyType != typeof(string);    // Check if property is not string

    foreach (var el in type.GetProperties().Where(query))
    {
        // create new instance of el cascade
        var elInstance = CascadeInitializer(el.PropertyType);
        el.SetValue(newObj, elInstance);
    }
    return newObj;
}

// a generic overload to easier usage
public T CascadeInitializer<T>() => (T)CascadeInitializer(typeof(T));
```

usage

```cs
var x =  CascadeInitializer<Envelope>();
```

---

also if you want to control what classes should be automatically initialized, you can add an empty interface `interface IInitializable` to your classes,  this way you can check what property is of `IInitializable` type in the `Func query`.

e.g

```cs
Func<PropertyInfo,bool> query = q
    => q.PropertyType.IsClass &&            // Check if property is a class
       q.CanWrite &&                        // Check if property is not readOnly
       q.PropertyType != typeof(string) &&  // Check if property is not string
       q.PropertyType.GetInterfaces()       // Check what classes should be initialize 
           .Any(i => i.Name == nameof(IInitializable) );

...
public interface IInitializable{}

public class Envelope : IInitializable {
.....
```

> test on dotnetfiddle :
>   https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xm8nEX

Comment: i'm sorry but i have 13 of reputation i can't...

<Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.>

Comment: now i'm getting an error on list type Parameter count mismatch..i tryied to do with this command  

el.SetValue(newObj, elInstance,new object[]{0}); but the response was


Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')

Comment: you can ignore list types if you want (just add another if condition for lists) or initialize lists like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38329808/786376

Answer (score 0):

You were only defining classes and did not have the properties for the classes.  See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetUserReq userReq = new GetUserReq();
            userReq.Envelope = new Envelope();
            GetUserResponse userResponse = new GetUserResponse();
            userResponse.Envelope = new Envelope();
            userReq.Body = new Body();
            userReq.Body.GetUser = new GetUser();
            userReq.Body.GetUser.ReturnedTags = new ReturnedTags();

            Boolean allReturnTags = true;
            if (allReturnTags)
            {
                userReq.Body.GetUser.ReturnedTags.AssociatedGroups = new AssociatedGroups();
                userReq.Body.GetUser.ReturnedTags.AssociatedDevices = new AssociatedDevices();
                userReq.Body.GetUser.ReturnedTags.AssociatedGroups.UserGroup = new UserGroup() { Name = "", UserRoles = new UserRoles() };
                userReq.Body.GetUser.ReturnedTags.AssociatedGroups.UserGroup.UserRoles = new UserRoles() { UserRole = "" };
            }

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GetUserReq));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, userReq);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "getUser", Namespace = "http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/9.1")]
        public GetUser GetUser { get; set; }
    }
    public class GetUser
    {
        public ReturnedTags ReturnedTags { get; set; }
    }
    public class ReturnedTags
    {
        public AssociatedGroups AssociatedGroups { get; set; }
        public AssociatedDevices AssociatedDevices { get; set; }
    }
    public class GetUserReq
    {
        public Envelope Envelope { get; set; }
        public Body Body { get; set; }

    }
    public class GetUserResponse
    {
        public Envelope Envelope { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Header", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public string Header { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "soapenv", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Soapenv { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "ns", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Ns { get; set; }
    }
    public class AssociatedGroups
    {
        public UserGroup UserGroup { get; set; }
    }
    public class AssociatedDevices
    {
    }
    public class UserGroup
    {
        public UserRoles UserRoles { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class UserRoles
    {
        public string UserRole { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,
the problemi is not the properties, the code above is a snippet of entire code that serialize the xml.
My question is if i can instantiate all properties of envelope and so on, with a foreach loop.

Thx you

Comment: What is the source of the data?  What does the output of the xml look like?  I usually use other methods to generate xml when doing a dynamic instantiate.  For example using xml linq you can generate a new element using : XElement newNode = new XElement("Name", "Value");  where the Name and Value are string.

Answer (score 0):

I did this code made from your example and modified for my neededs

```
    public T AllReturnTags<T>() => (T)AllReturnTags(typeof(T));

    public object AllReturnTags(Type type)
    {
        var newObj = Activator.CreateInstance(type); // create new instance of your target class

        Func<PropertyInfo, bool> query = q
             => q.PropertyType.IsClass &&         
                q.CanWrite;                  

        foreach (var el in type.GetProperties().Where(query))
        {
            // create new instance of el cascade
            if (el.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                el.SetValue(newObj, "", null);
            }
            if (el.PropertyType == typeof(Int32))
            {
                el.SetValue(newObj, 0, null);
            }
            if (el.PropertyType.IsClass && el.PropertyType != typeof(string) && el.PropertyType != typeof(Int32) && el.PropertyType.IsGenericType == true && el.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
            {
                var elInstance = AllReturnTags(el.PropertyType);
                Type itemType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(elInstance.GetType());
                IList res = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(itemType);
                res.Add(elInstance);
                try { el.SetValue(newObj, res, null); } catch {  };
            }
            if (el.PropertyType.IsClass && el.PropertyType != typeof(string) && el.PropertyType != typeof(Int32) && el.PropertyType.IsGenericType != true )
            {
                var elInstance = AllReturnTags(el.PropertyType);
                try { el.SetValue(newObj, elInstance, null); } catch { return elInstance; };
            }

        }
        return newObj;
    }
```

This seems to work with single items and lists.
Thx you @AliReza