# Instantiate a class based in a already instantiated

Tags: c#

I have a method similar to this:

```
public void DoSomething<T>() where T : BaseClass
```

Which I use as:

```
DoSomething<MyClass>();
```

My problem is: I have the already instantiated class stored in a variable, and I would like to use it to call this method.

Exemple:
I have a variable to store the class;

```
BaseClass instantiated;
```

At some point, I instantiate

```
instantiated = new MyClass(); //Inherits from BaseClass
```

At another time, I need to call the method, but all i have is the "instantiated" variable. What do I enter in the method's <>?

```
DoSomething<?>();
```

Comment: Change your method signature to `public void DoSomething<T>(T obj) where T : BaseClass` and then call it like `DoSomething(instantiated);`. Now inside `DoSomething()` you can work with `obj` however you need.

Comment: What is the T type used for? Can you provide an implementation of the method?

Comment: Do you know T at compile time? Or only at runtime?

Comment: I'm super curious what you are doing inside `DoSomething` that it can effectively do whatever it does given either just a type (that can't be `new()`d up) or an instance.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just need an interface and have "DoSomething" depend on the interface instead of it being generic?

Comment: Generic methods are for return types. I.e. `public void DoSomething(BaseClass obj)` [achieves the same thing](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bxy77n) as @itsme86. As your return type is `void` then I would assume that this is actually a badly worded [duplicate of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078914/creating-a-generict-type-instance-with-a-variable-containing-the-type)

Comment: Inside I instantiate the class and do what i need. Exemple: var obj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), param1, param2);

Comment: @LeonardoLimaAlmeida That doesn't require a generic method; you could use `public void DoSomething(Type myType)` and then `Activator.CreateInstance(myType,param1,param2) as BaseClass;` instead

Comment: I need to instantiate the class inside the method, not out of it.

Comment: @LukeBriggs, if i use like this, i can't restrict for classes that inherits from BaseClass

Comment: @LeonardoLimaAlmeida any class that inherited from `BaseClass` could be used in his method example.  That's polymorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic methods let us have a custom return type. As you're not using that, i.e. your return type is `void`, then it doesn't actually need to be a generic method at all:

```
public void DoSomething(BaseClass myInstance){

    // Instance it and cast to a BaseClass:
    BaseClass obj=(BaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(myInstance.GetType(),param1,param2);

    // Do anything else with obj.

}
```

As you say you've already got an existing object, then that is called like so:

```
DoSomething(thatObject);
```

Alternatively - this is the more common form - define a virtual Clone() method:

```
public class BaseClass{

 public virtual BaseClass Clone(){

   return new BaseClass();

 }

}

public class MyClass : BaseClass{

 public override BaseClass Clone(){

   return new MyClass();

 }

}

...

BaseClass myClone=thatObject.Clone();
```

*If we were* going to *return* the newly created object, then that's something a little different. It can make good use of generics:

```
public T DoSomething<T>() where T:BaseClass{

    // Instance it and cast to T:
    T obj=(T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T),param1,param2);

    // Do anything else with obj.

    return obj;
}
```

With our call like this:

```
MyClass myClass=DoSomething<MyClass>();
```

This can't be done with a runtime known type because then the return type is unknown too.

[Here's an example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0g7n0P) of that last one in action.

Comment: i agree! And i can call like DoSomething(typeof(MainScreen)), right? This way, i can pass a type that not inherits from BaseClass, which will generate an error. But apparently it is the best way out =/

Comment: @LeonardoLimaAlmeida I've made a few edits which should help some more :)