# Create instance with type object during runtime

Tags: c#, reflection, types, initialization

I have the following code

```
//^process a aquery and return DataTable
DataTable d t= dbConnect.ProcessQuery(strquery);
Type t = dt.Columns[0].DataType.GetType();
```

How to create objects of type `t` that will receive the `dt[0][..]` ?

I know that `dt.Rows[][]` will be of type `t`

I need to create anagrammatically  variables of type `t`

Comment: Why not just stuff them into objects and figure out the correct thing to do with the object afterwards?

Comment: Look at Convert.ChangeType and see where it leads you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First step is to retrieve the actual type you want to create. Most probably, the name of the type is stored in the database as a String. So you call

```
var typeName = "System.Int32";
var type = System.Type.GetType(typeName);
```

Now that you have the actual type you want to instantiate, call

```
var obj = System.Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

In most cases you would have a common base interface for all types that you would ever use in each scenario:

```
var i = (IFormattable)obj;
```

Now you can call the methods on the interface and they will be executed on the actual type.

```
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("0", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Knaģis already provided the appropriate answer, but I wanted to point out that this line of code is incorrect:

```
Type T =dt.Columns[0].DataType.GetType();
```

This will always return `Type`, not `string`, `int`, etc. That's because the Type of `DataType` is `Type`. Use this instead:

```
Type T =dt.Columns[0].DataType;
```

Also, you are using the naming convention for a generic type. While it's a bit confusing on the first read, there's nothing "wrong" with it. Just be aware that *there's a difference between a generic type and a variable*. For example, give the code in your question, you would **not** be able to use this code:

```
var x = new List<T>;
```

In the context of your code, `T` is a variable, not a generic type, so the above would cause a compile-time error.

See this question for more information:
[Generics in C#, using type of a variable as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107845/generics-in-c-using-type-of-a-variable-as-parameter)