# C# passing generic type to another class

Tags: c#, class, generics, argument-passing

I wanna know is there any way to pass generic type to another Class as an argument.
In other words. I have `SomeClass<T>` and `AnotherClass`.
I wanna `AnotherClass` to have an instance field of Type `<T>` who would be initialized in constructor.

(I want `SomeClass` to be list of `AnotherClass` objects. Another Class would have 3 instance fields reference to previous `AnotherClass` object reference to next `AnotherClass` object and a `T` type field.

Comment: If you're looking for runtime type deduction, as in not making your class generic and making a member of the class of a variant type, I don't believe that's possible (out of the box) with C#. You can do it in a makeshift way where the constructor takes in an object, and stores both the object and the Type of the object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107845/generics-in-c-using-type-of-a-variable-as-parameter

Comment: To me, this question does not look like a duplicate of the one referenced above the original question. In _this_ question, the type would be known at compile time. It is about enforcing that related classes use the same actual type for the generic type parameter when used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're making a generic container. You need something like:

```
class Container<T>
{
    public T Value;

    public Container( T rhs )
    {
        Value = rhs;
    }
}
```

That's basic generics in C#. If you provide more description, I can better answer your question, but based on the info provided, this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Ok but how can i pass ListClass generic type <T> to Container class?

Comment: public Container( List<T> list ) where ListClass of type T shares the same underlying type as Container. So if they both share the same T, you can pass a List of T into a Container of T.

Comment: Thank you very much i think i understand it and looks good for me.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Can you mark this as the selected answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass<T> {
    public List<T> myList;

    public MyClass() {
        this.myList = new List<T>();
    }
}
```

Like that? I'm not sure I 100% understand the question.