# Pass concrete object type as parameter for generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dynamic, types

I have an API using generic method as follow

```
public static class DataProvider
{
    public static Boolean DeleteDataObject<T>(Guid uid, IDbConnection dbConnection)
    {
        // Do something here
    }

    public static IDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        // Get connection
    }
}
```

My application contains classes generated using CodeDOM at runtime, and in order to keep track of I created an interface called `IDataObject`. I am trying to pass the concrete type of each object to the generic method above as follow:

```
public static Boolean PurgeDataObject(this IDataObject dataObject, Guid uid)
{
    return DataProvider.DeleteDataObject<T>(uid, DataProvider.GetConnection());
}
```

`dataObject` contains an instance of a class that inherit from `IDataObject`. I am interested in getting that type and pass it as `T`. I am trying to find out if it is possible to somehow use `dynamic` here. `typeof()` and `GetType()` does not work as stated in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107845/generics-in-c-using-type-of-a-variable-as-parameter)

Comment: There are some tricks to use dynamic as a bridge between reflection and generics, but they require an instance. If you don't have an instance, MakeGenericMethod is your main tool. Or a non-generic API...

Comment: @MarcGravell: `dataObject` is an instance which contains the Type information I am trying to extract and pass. Have a look at Jon's answer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I suspect you want something like this:

```
public static Boolean PurgeDataObject(this IDataObject dataObject, Guid uid)
{
    return PurgeDataObjectImpl((dynamic) dataObject, uid);
}

private static Boolean PurgeDataObjectImpl<T>(T dataObject, Guid uid)
    where T : IDataObject
{
    return DataProvider.DeleteDataObject<T>(uid, DataProvider.GetConnection());
}
```

That uses `dataObject` dynamically, getting the "execution-time compiler" to perform type inference to work out `T`.

You *could* just use reflection to do this yourself, using `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod` - but this way is certainly less code.

Comment: The call in the first method should be `return PurgeDataObjectImpl((dynamic) dataObject, uid);` (wrong method name, less than 6 characters, I can't edit)

Comment: +1 -this dynamic cast is perfect for a little corner case that's been baffling me for the past hour. i just hope i don't `over-use` it, in favour of thinking out the options - so increadibly simple and too the point. thanks