# return generic IEnumerable when passing concrete type parameter for a generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dynamic, types

This code example is taken from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16491759/98706

```
public static Boolean PurgeDataObject(this IDataObject dataObject, Guid uid)
{
    return PurgeDataObjectImpl((dynamic) dataObject, uid);
}

private static Boolean PurgeDataObjectImpl<T>(T dataObject, Guid uid)
    where T : IDataObject
{
    return DataProvider.DeleteDataObject<T>(uid, DataProvider.GetConnection());
}
```

I have a similar situation where I want to return the relevant EF entities based on a type at execution time, to try and clean up some existing inherited code as shown below :(

The difference is I want the function to return an `IEnumerable<T>`

The `GetFilteredData` won't have a concept of `T` so I get the compile error of `The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

```
    private IEnumerable<T> GetFilteredData(Type entityType, SortedList<string, string> filterList, List<int> weeks)
    {
        return GetFilteredDataImpl((dynamic)entityType, filterList, weeks);
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> GetFilteredDataImpl<T>(T entityType, SortedList<string, string> filterList, List<int> weeks) where T : EntityObject
    {
        var data = _modelContext.CreateObjectSet<T>().AsExpandable();
          // do more filtering and then call .ToList() to return a List<T>
    }
```

Comment: Well, in the `GetFilteredData`, how is the compiler supposed to know what T is? It's not constrained and not defined as a parameter.

Comment: @LightStriker yea I put a comment in my question saying `The GetFilteredData won't have a concept of T so I get the compile error` I guess I am now looking for an alternative approach.

Comment: How do you imagine the code using GetFilteredData will look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert the `Type` class to a generic `T` parameter without using reflection. The parameter also needs to be present as part of the method.

Jon Skeet was using type inference by example combined with generics in order to guarantee type safety and simplify the generic code. Unfortunately you will lose that type safety using `Type` and reflection.

```
private IEnumerable<EntityObject> GetFilteredData(Type entityType,
                                                  SortedList<string, string> filterList,
                                                  List<int> weeks)
{
    var method = typeof(<class>).GetMethod("GetFilteredDataImpl");
    var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(entityType);
    return (IEnumerable<EntityObject>)generic.Invoke(this, new[] { filterList, weeks });
}

private IEnumerable<T> GetFilteredDataImpl<T>(SortedList<string, string> filterList,
                                              List<int> weeks)
    where T : EntityObject
{
    var data = _modelContext.CreateObjectSet<T>().AsExpandable();
      // do more filtering and then call .ToList() to return a List<T>
}
```

However, you could create an object to pass in.

```
private IEnumerable<EntityObject> GetFilteredData(Type entityType, SortedList<string, string> filterList, List<int> weeks)
{
    var instance = (EntityObject)Activator.CreateInstance(entityType);
    return GetFilteredDataImpl((dynamic)instance, filterList, weeks);
}

private IEnumerable<T> GetFilteredDataImpl<T>(T entityType, SortedList<string, string> filterList, List<int> weeks) where T : EntityObject
{
    var data = _modelContext.CreateObjectSet<T>().AsExpandable();
      // do more filtering and then call .ToList() to return a List<T>
}
```

This will still return an `IEnumerable<EntityObject>`, but it will generate garbage and you're trading an `ArgumentException` for an `InvalidCastException`.

Comment: If i change the return type of `GetFilteredData` to `IEnumerable<EntityObject>` then my existing code works fine, because of `GetFilteredDataImpl` and using `dynamic`.. I don't need to make further reflection changes. but then my problem is I then have to do lots of casting of the returned result in other functions so I can set the correct properties, which is what I am trying to avoid :(

Comment: The problem that you're running into is using a non-generic method to get generic results. You're going to lose type information going from generic to non-generic.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I definately need to rethink this to fit it in with the current code. Thanks again.