# Dynamically pass class and method names to a method using generics

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I want to pass in dynamically a class name and a method name to a method and keep this dynamic, I'm understanding that I should use generics and possible constraints.

Example, I have a class

```
MemberRequestDTO    (contains several properties)
```

I also that a Method called

```
RecordsToRetrieve
```

Using some reflection I was wanting to dynamically get the values of the properties, which I figured out how to do that, but then I realized that is is too hard code and tightly coupled of which I figured time to refactor and create a method with a signature that uses generics with constraints.  having trouble with understand the use of  and the constraints etc..

So I want to pass in a class name and be able to use it in the method, with reflection I plan to use it like:

`Type  type = typeof(classname);`

I started reading and researching and I start playing with code like this:

```
public void GetTypeValues<T>() where T : class , new()
```

1. How do I pass in the class name of MemberRequestDTO?
2. What does the Generic  new for me?
3. How do I pass a class name into the parens ()?
4. If I use  does it also get pass into parens?
5. How can I pass in class and method?
6. Reading the above  "Where T has the constraints (enforced) to be of type "class AND new() ?

A little lost and confused on this, forgive me.

EDIT:

Based on the answers and some research, I'm understanding this a bit more:

Lets forget about me trying to pass in a method, say I just want to pass in a class

Say the class with properties looks like this

```
 public class MemberRequestDTO
 {

    public DateTime DateRequested { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
  }
```

Then I will New this up

```
var memberRequestDTO = new MemberRequestDTO();
```

Then I want to pass this to class into a method that is generic

How do I go about passing an instance of a object into a generic method?  What about the signature , example   public void GetTypeValues() where T : class , new()
Would I want to have the contraints of class and new() ?

For the above, is T the instance of the class?   Thus the purpose is that I can be

Saying

```
GetTypeValues(memberRequestDTO)
```

( this is my actual question , **pass into whatever class I instantiated and that let the method "handle" dealing with that class with looping through the properties and getting me the name values of the properties dynamically**  and yes it probably will not remain a void method )

Should passing in memberRequestDTO be with quotes or without?   I want to be able to pass in any instance of a class to the member to then manipulate it more.  ()   should T be there ?  should the parens ()  be empty or contain an generic parameter for the class object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your answers:

1. `GetTypeValues<MemberRequestDTO>()`
2. `new()` is a constraint for the `Type Parameter - T`. It says that the type argument `T` must have a public parameterless constructor. In your case, `MemberRequestDTO` class must a public parameterless constructor like below:

   ```
   public class MemberRequestDTO
   {
       public MemberRequestDTO() { ... }
   }
   ```
3. As a class name is of `reference type`, you can pass it as a `type` into the parens like: `SomeMethod(typeof(MemberRequestDTO));` where the signature of the method be `void SomeMethod(Type type) { }`
4. If you pass the class as a `type parameter` as in point (1), it does not get passed into the parens()
5. 
6. `class` constraint implies that "The type argument must be a reference type; this applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type."
   and `new()` constraint implies that "The type argument must have a public parameterless constructor. When used together with other constraints, the new() constraint must be specified last."

---

### EDIT:

If I catch your point, then the generic method definition would be something like:

```
public void GetTypeValues<T>(T typeObject) where T : class
{
    // typeObject specific operations
}
```

That uses `typeObject` dynamically, getting the "execution-time compiler" to perform type inference to work out `T`. [See the reference here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16491759/1977104) Moreover, imho, you don't need the `new ()` constraint on `T` here.

After that, you can pass an instance of any class to this method like below:

```
var memberRequestDTO = new MemberRequestDTO();
GetTypeValues((dynamic) memberRequestDTO);
```

---

### EDIT 2:

**USAGE: Get Type Values dynamically using Reflection**

This method returns the property values wrapping into `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`.

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetTypeValues<T>(T typeObject) where T : class
{
    // typeObject specific operations
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> typeValues = 
        typeObject
        .GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Select(property => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(property.Name, property.GetValue(typeObject)));
    return typeValues;
}
```

Comment: I added in more information to my question.  Hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: I have updated my answer above. Please have a look in the `EDIT` section. and +1 for this good question !

Comment: How do I use typeObject,    example    Type type = typeof(typeObject) this cannot be resolved ... i'm using this signature    public void GetTypeValues<T>(T typeObject) where T : class

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please look into `EDIT 2`. If you have any further query, feel free to ask. Thanks!

Comment: At a loss for why you are casting to dynamic ((dynamic) memberRequestDTO. Since you specify the generic as <T> and then use T in the signature, the compiler is smart enough to figure out T is whatever type you passed in. Even if you did not use T as a parameter you could say GetTypeValues<MemberRequestDTO>, but you should never have to cast it to a dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I pass in the class name of MemberRequestDTO ?

You already have one. In a generic method "Type parameter" in this case `T` will be the name of type you're interested in.

```
public void GetTypeValues<T>() where T : class , new()
{
    string typeName = typeof(T).Name;
}
```

> What does the Generic new for me?

It is a contraint which will prevent you to pass any type without public parameterless constructor. In other words it will allow you to new up type passed in as "Type parameter"

```
public void GetTypeValues<T>() where T : class , new()
{
    T instance = new T();//This is not possible without new constraint
}
```

> How do I pass a class name into the parens () ?
>
> If I use does it also get pass into parens?

Not sure what is that `parens()` Need more info to answer this.

> How can I pass in class and method?

If I understand correctly "Type parameter" `T` is the runtime type which you use. So you get a `Type` there. Am not sure about what you mean by class? Class cannot be passed only instances can be passed.

For methods there are number of ways. You can pass `MethodInfo` or method name or A delegate, or a `MethodCallExpression` etc.

> Reading the above "Where T has the constraints (enforced) to be of
>   type "class AND new() ?

Yes. class constraint prevents you from passing value types, new() constraint allows you to new up things.

Read more about generics [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Does  "T" represent the MemberRequestDTO that I new up an instance and pass in?  What I realize that I don't want to do is hard code , thus      Type type = typeof(MemberRequestDTO);   is not good , i want to use reflection to end up doing   typeof(T)   -- which T is supposed to be the instance of MemberRequestDTO  , then , i further do not want to be using  sbBuilder.Append(value + " : " + getFalpaRequest.FirstName).AppendLine();   as I want a generic to determine the property name value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about what you want to do but I'll give it a shot.  I can see two possible interpretations and they differ on what the caller is starting with and what you're trying to achieve.

Interpretation #1: The caller starts out knowing the *name* of the class and the *name* of the method it wants to invoke later, using an object it has in hand.  This can be achieved as follows:

```
public Func<object, object> RecordMethod(string typeName, string methodName)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
    var method = type.GetMethod(methodName);
    return (object o) => method.Invoke(o, new object[0]);
}

var method = RecordMethod("MemberRequestDTO", "RecordsToRetrieve");

// later that day ...
MemberRequestDTO someObj = ...;
var result = method.Invoke(someObj);
```

This is fine if you need to work with type names and method names dynamically, e.g. from user input.  Note that this approach requires the use of `object` throughout, and will only work with a method that takes no parameters.  Also note that in this way the type cannot be guaranteed to have a no-arg constructor, so the caller must provide the object himself.

Interpretation #2: The caller starts out knowing the *actual* class and the *actual* method it wants to invoke later, using an object that can be constructed later.  This can be achieved as follows:

```
public Func<TOutput> CaptureMethod<TInput, TOutput>(Func<TInput, TOutput> method) 
where TInput : new()
{
    return () =>
    {
        var source = new TInput();
        return method(source);
    };
}

var capturedMethod = (MemberRequestDTO dto) => dto.RecordsToRetrieve();

// later that day ...
var result = capturedMethod();
```

This captures a known method and returns a function which, when invoked, will instantiate your class and call the method on it.  This is a more static approach (the caller knows more than in the previous example) and is able to enforce a constraint that the type being worked with must have a no-arg constructor.

I don't know if I've answered your question but this should at least give you some ideas.