# IEnumerable<T> with dynamic generic - C#

Tags: generics, ienumerable

I am trying to achieve following, is it possible?

```
Type T = Type.GetType("EntityName")
IEnumerable<T> entities = BaseRepository.GetEntities(searchCriteria) as IEnumerable<T>();
```

Comment: No, you couldn't do that. You should probably think about creating a good *generic* base repository and think about what methods (simple CRUD) you could universally support and then how to customize the rest. Some use `Expression<Func<>>` parameters to allow arbitrarily many query possibilities, others create custom derived repositories that know the specific queries to support while allowing little to no additional parameterization.

Comment: Answered here: [Generics in C#, using type of a variable as parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2107845/254830). You should think about doing this another way, though, like what @user414076 is pointing out. Jon Skeet talks about that a little in his answer.