# Code Refactoring C#

Tags: c#

I am working on a small application to get a grips with C# and i have written a small application that currently adds up values of items (currently predefined) Here is what i have so far:

```
//Defining classes
 public class Item1{
  public string Type{get{return "Item1";}}
 }
 public class Item2{
  public string Type{get{return "Item2";}}
 }

//Methods
public void CalcItems(Item1 item1, int val){
 this.Log(item1.Type + "Val:" + val);
 this.total += val;
}

public void CalcItems(Item2 item2, int val){
 this.Log(item2.Type + "Val:" + val);
 this.total += val;
}

//Calling these methods
Items.CalcItems(new Item1(), 30);
Items.CalcItems(new Item2(), 12);
```

How can I pass both Item1 and Item 2 through one calc method?

Comment: What do you mean by "group"? Do you want both `Item1` and `Item2` to be passed to the same `CalcItems` method?

Comment: @Jamiec  Yes, pass both the two Items through the same method. Sorry couldnt find the wording haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `Interface`:

```
public interface IItem
{
    string Type { get; }
}
```

Then implement the interface on your class declarations:

```
public class Item1 : IItem
{
    ...
    public string Type { get; }
    ...
}

public class Item2 : IItem
{
    ...
    public string Type { get; }
    ...
}
```

Now we can define the method `CalcItems()` as accepting an `IItem` parameter:

```
public void CalcItems(IItem item, int val)
{
    this.Log(item1.Type + "Val:" + val);
    this.total += val;
}
```

Such that the following would now reference the same method:

```
Items.CalcItems(new Item1(), 30);
Items.CalcItems(new Item2(), 12);
```

Comment: How could i implement this with all classes, that you can see in the question being in separate files.

Comment: You can implement `IItems` on your class definitions.  If you do not have access to the source code, inherit from the classes you are using in order to implement the interface.  (e.g., `public class MyItem1 : Item1, IItem` would be a possible class declaration).

Comment: Perfect! Do you have any recommendations on any reading materials which I could go through for programming in C#, As my knowledge in it is not as proficient as other languages. Thanks

Comment: Hands-on practice is always best; search for your answers with resources like SO.  Also, [dotNetPearls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/) is a good resource giving some good explanations for frequently encountered situations.

Answer (score 1):

Add an IItem interface to your items, and replace Item1 in Calcitems with iitem. Then you dont need both calcItems

Answer (score 1):

You could define an interface for both `Item1` and `Item2` as they both share the common property `Type`.

[**MSDN:** Interfaces (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx)

```
public interface IMyItem
{
    string Type;
}

public class Item1 : IMyItem
{
    public string Type{get{return "Item1";}}
}
public class Item2: IMyItem
{
    public string Type{get{return "Item2";}}
}

public void CalcItems(IMyItem item, int val){
    this.Log(item.Type + "Val:" + val);
    this.total += val;
}

Items.CalcItems(new Item1(), 30);
Items.CalcItems(new Item2(), 12);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107845/generics-in-c-using-type-of-a-variable-as-parameter). Define an interface for your Item objects and declare the method like so:

```
 void CalcItems<T>(T item, int val) where T : IItem
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the refactoring using the Strategy design pattern. Declare an interface and implement that interface to your Item1 and Item2 class. Do the calculation operation using that interface.

```
public interface IItem {
    string Type { get; }
}

public class Item1: IItem {
    public string Type{get{return "Item1";}}
}

public class Item2: IItem {
    public string Type{get{return "Item2";}}
}

public void CalcItems(IItem item, int val){
    this.Log(item.Type + "Val:" + val);
    this.total += val;
}

Items.CalcItems(new Item1(), 30);
Items.CalcItems(new Item2(), 12);
```