# Dynamically populate generic list of objects without concrete data type

Tags: c#, reflection, datatable, generic-list, dynamic-binding

I have a database with around 100 or so table. What I am trying to do is the following:

1. Get a list of tables in the database.
2. Loop through each table in the list, and select all records in the table into a Data Table.
3. For each Data Table, dynamically generate a Generic List of POCO classes
4. Read each Data Row and populate the object, then add it to the list.

I am getting through items 1 and 2 fine. But for items 3 and 4 I am having trouble. Here is the code I have:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(tableName);
var list = Utility.BindList<type>(dataTable);
```

The exception I get is: "'type' is a variable but is used like a type."

And thinking about it, it makes sense. Of course, if I enter the actual class instead of type it works fine:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(tableName);
var list = Utility.BindList<Person>(dataTable);
```

But I don't want to have to hard code any actual classes. By the way, here is the signature of the BindList method I am calling above (this part is working fine):

```
public static List<T> BindList<T>(DataTable dt)
{
    // Turn Data Table into Generic List

    return list
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks!

---

**Update: The solution was as follows, provided by Tyress:**

```
Type type = Assembly.Load("[NAMESPACE PATH]").GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == tableName);
var method = typeof(Utility).GetMethod("BindList").MakeGenericMethod(type);
var bindResult = method.Invoke(null, new[] { datatable });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generics in C#, using type of a variable as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107845/generics-in-c-using-type-of-a-variable-as-parameter)

Comment: Actually this is a different issue. What I am trying to do is to pass in a concrete data type of custom classes into a Generic function.

Comment: No it is not. You don't have a concrete data type. You only have a type, that is known by runtime (You written it yourself in your question title)

Comment: Actually part of the solution overlaps with the thread you referenced. The big part that was missing however was the way the "type" variable is fetched to avoid fetching null (first line). Still, thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2. For each Data Table, dynamically generate a Generic List of POCO
>    classes
>
> But I don't want to have to hard code any actual classes.

I think these two statements are contradictory? What do you need POCO classes for?
`dynamic` / `ExpandoObject` can be used for your generic function (instead of `type`) but I don't really see why you can't just use `Dictionary` if you don't need POCO classes.

--

Edit based on my understanding:

```
var method = typeof(Utility).GetMethod("BindList").MakeGenericMethod(type);
var bindResult = method.Invoke(null, new[] { dataTable });
```

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain it right. Suppose we have 2 tables called "Person" and "Address" in the database. What I am trying to do is to loop through all these classes, and pass in the class data type for the data object class to the generic function one by one, have it populate the generic list of that object type and then return the list. The POCO class is essentially similar to EF Classes, even though they are not actually related to EF. Each table column in the database has a property in the POCO class with the same data type.

Comment: @DigiOzMultimedia Oh I see now, I thought the classes didn't exist yet and you want to make them during runtime, which is complicated. I'll edit my answer based on what I understand

Comment: Nicely done Tyress! The only thing I had to change was the way I was getting the "type" variable because Type.GetType only works when the class is in the same assembly as the executing code. Because the class was in a different assembly I had to use "Type type = Assembly.Load("[ASSEMBLY NAMESPACE").GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == tableName);" to get the type. From there your code works flawlessly. Thank you VERY much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Simply go for entity framework instead of inventing it yourself once more.

Use EF code first and reverse engineer entities from database.

Comment: There is just a small problem with that. EF is extremely slow and does not support the 5000+ tables in SQL that I am trying to support for other projects (for this one there is only 100, but I am using this as a template elsewhere). By using ADO.NET I have managed to increase the speed of the application 100 fold and support as many database tables as I need.