# Use typeof in generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I Create Generic class like this:

```
public class Sample<T> where T : class
{
    public DoSomething();
}
```

then I create new class :

```
public class Sample2
{
    Sample<Sample2> obj=new Sample<Sample2>();
}
```

why can't i use the below code to create an instance of `Sample` class in `Sample2` class?

```
        Sample<typeof<this>> obj=new Sample<typeof<this>>();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107845/generics-in-c-using-type-of-a-variable-as-parameter

Comment: Mainly because generics are evaluated at compile-time. The `typeof` function returns a Type class at runtime. You could use Activator.CreateInstance instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx

Comment: Additionally, I don't think you can reference `this` in a field initializer, since the object has not been constructed at that point

Comment: Because: 1. `typeof` is not generic. It's `typeof(...)`. 2. `typeof` takes a type literal (or parameter), not a reference. 3. Generics and `Type`s do no mix (not without reflection): either use strong-type generics, or reflection and `Type`/`typeof`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer is simple Generics need to be `Compile time` but what you're doing is obviously not known during `Compile time`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. First, generics is also a .Net run time feature, not just a C# compile time feature. Second, certainly the type of the current class is known at compile time? If anything, you would not know the type of `T` inside `Sample<T>` (terrible name), but this is not the case.

Comment: Makes sense, but not completely true.  Read this answer to see how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/687420/72350

Comment: @Diego thanks for the comment. I'm aware of the reflection approach but in general reflection should be avoided unless it's really really needed.