# Construct class using string name for generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I have a Json deserialiser class that is created using a generic parameter like this:

```
Deserializer<T> results = Deserializer<T>.FromFile(file);
```

Where T is the interface that an arbitrary number of types implement.

I'd like T to be chosen by the name of the class in the form of a string such as "Person"
and the class Person implements T.

So it could be written like this:

```
Deserializer<Type.GetType("Person")> results = Deserializer<Type.GetType("Person")>.FromFile(file);
```

I have tried exactly this above and it gives me an error:

```
Using the generic type 'Deserializer<T>' requires 1 type arguments
```

I've also looked at this

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/80690cd9-d1f2-4888-9c95-62305de9ced4/using-typegettype-with-generics

but trying to use some of these resulted in other errors such as:

```
randomVariable is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'
```

Is there a mistake in my code or am I going about this the wrong way?

How can I get this to work?

***Solution***
My final code was

```
        Type genericType = typeof(Deserializer<>);
        Type[] typeArgs = {Type.GetType("Person")};
        Type deserialiserType = genericType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
        object repository = Activator.CreateInstance(deserialiserType);

        MethodInfo genericMethod = deserialiserType.GetMethod("FromFile");
        genericMethod.Invoke(repository, new[] {file});
```

Thank you all for your help

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your goal, what you say doesn't entirely compute.  Are you trying to build an `interface` or `class` based on the JSON or are you trying to assign the value to a class that exist?

Comment: Tell us what serializer you are using so we can give you some advice.

Comment: What if the class name provided implements multiple interfaces?

Comment: I think this may be quite useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107536/convert-string-to-type-c-sharp. From Jon Skeet's own mouth!

Comment: @barrick I can guarantee it only implements once class ever.

Comment: @Ellimist0 In that case, to get to the interface, you can call FindInterfaces() on the type returned from the advice above; this will return an Array of Type[], and so the item at index 0 will be the interface you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the answer in ModiX's link applied to your code, should result in something like this:

```
Type genericType = typeof(Deserializer<>);
Type[] typeArgs = { Type.GetType("Person") };
Type deserializerType = genericType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

object deserializer = Activator.CreateInstance(deserializerType);

MethodInfo fromFileMethod = deserializerType.GetMethod("FromFile");
fromFileMethod.Invoke(deserializer, new[] { file });
```

The line

```
MethodInfo closedMethod = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Something));
```

is used if your method is generic, in your case if it would look something like this:

```
Deserializer<T>.FromFile<T2>(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the wrong approach because the generic field requires a type and not an object of the `Type` class.

However, there is already a solution. [How do I create a generic class from a string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687363/how-do-i-create-a-generic-class-from-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Thanks for the link, that gets me all the way to the line:
`MethodInfo closedMethod = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Something));`

But I don't know what Something is, which brings me full circle to the original problem

Comment: Thank you, I went one step too far when I could invoke the method using the genericMethod option

Answer (score 0):

Generic parameters must be "real type names", because they should be resolvable at build-time.

Type.GetType is a runtime method.

You've got many choices, for example :

- If you absolutely need to pass the type which is stored in a string as you've explained, you could instantiate the whole deserializer by reflection : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b8ytshk6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
- See if you can pass type instance in parameter of your deserializer :

  Deserializer.FromFile(file, Type.GetType("person"));

This will give you the ability tu use runtime types.

- See if deserializer can "automatically" deserialize to an instance of the good type (boxed in object) and just cast it to expected type.
- Change your implementation to call Deserializer with the good generic parameter according the data to deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what your attempting to do is implement this:

```
public interface Dynamic <T>
{
     T GetObject(string derserialize);
}
```

So essentially your class would inherit `Dynamic`, defining your generic type at that moment.  Then you would essentially *implicit* or *explicitly* implement the method `GetObject`.  It would accept your JSON data, then you could perform your desired logic to return it as the *type* of your choice.